# How to filter on index "Date" and add the first new future date in a new column

Tags: python, date, datetime, filter

I have a Dataframe name "Data" that have daily date as index (DatetimeIndex) and 1 column with price. I want to add a new column that will gave me the first future date between the 03-27 and 09-27 of future year.

Here's an example of my Data frame

```
                Price
date
2021-12-31       60
2021-01-01       60
2021-01-02       60
2021-01-03       60
...
2021-03-25       60
2021-03-26       60
2021-03-27       60
2021-03-28       60
...
2021-09-25       60
2021-09-26       60
2021-09-27       60
2021-09-28       60
2021-09-30       60

Heres the result that I would like :
                Price        New Date
date
2021-12-31       60         2021-03-27
2021-01-01       60         2021-03-27
2021-01-02       60         2021-03-27
2021-01-03       60         2021-03-27
...
2021-03-25       60         2021-03-27
2021-03-26       60         2021-03-27
2021-03-27       60         2021-03-27
2021-03-28       60        **2021-09-27**
...
2021-09-25       60         2021-09-27
2021-09-26       60         2021-09-27
2021-09-27       60         2021-09-27
2021-09-28       60       **2022-03-27**
2021-09-30       60       **2022-03-27**
```

I tried to create a column month, an array with conditions and add a new column base on those conditions but it don't work... I also try a loop but won't work neither...

Here's the code that I tried, but would love an easy solution to my problem :

```
Data = xl_file.parse('Data',date_parser = ["date"], index_col = "date")

Data["Month"]= pd.DatetimeIndex(Data.index).month

#conditions = [
   (Data["Month"] >= 3) & (Data.index <= np.datetime64(str(int(Data["Year"])) + "-09-27")) & (Data.index > np.datetime64(str(int(Data["Year"])) + "-03-27")),
    (Data["Month"] > 3) & (Data.index > np.datetime64(str(int(Data["Year"])) + "-09-27")) & (Data.index > np.datetime64(str(int(Data["Year"])) + "-03-27")),
    (Data["Month"] < 3) & (Data.index < np.datetime64(str(int(Data["Year"])) + "-09-27"))]

choices = [1, 2, 3]

Data['Filter'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
Data.loc[Data["Filter"]== 1, "New_Date"]= str(int(Data["Year"])) + "-09-27"
Data.loc[Data["Filter"]== 2, "New_Date"]= str(int(Data["Year"]+1)) + "-03-27"
Data.loc[Data["Filter"]== 3, "New_Date"]= str(int(Data["Year"])) + "-03-27"
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of applying the change should not be reversed:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)), columns = ['date'])
df['price'] = 60

idx1 = (df['date'].dt.month < 3) | ((df['date'].dt.month == 3) & (df['date'].dt.day <= 27))
idx2 = (df['date'].dt.month < 9) | ((df['date'].dt.month == 9) & (df['date'].dt.day <= 27))
idx3 = (df['date'].dt.month > 9) | ((df['date'].dt.month == 9) & (df['date'].dt.day > 27))
df.loc[idx3, 'New Date'] = df.loc[idx3, 'date'].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(day=27, month=3, year = dt.year + 1))
df.loc[idx2, 'New Date'] = df.loc[idx2, 'date'].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(day=27, month=9))
df.loc[idx1, 'New Date'] = df.loc[idx1, 'date'].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(day=27, month=3))
```

output

```
    date     price  New Date
85  2021-03-27  60  2021-03-27
86  2021-03-28  60  2021-09-27
269 2021-09-27  60  2021-09-27
270 2021-09-28  60  2022-03-27
```

Since your Data has date as an index you would have to set it as column and set it back later:

```
df = df.reset_index()
# run the code
df = df.set_index('name of your date index')
```

Comment: And if the date range is variable ? It start from 2001-12-31 and do to today. It will be udate daily also ?

Comment: what do you mean? the code above did not specify any date.

Comment: This define the date range no ? :
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)), columns = ['date'])

Comment: this generates the sample data to run the code. You have to supply your own data to use it.